# FileReader onload only works the second time around in browsers

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm working on in-browser image processing with HTML5 and have a weird issue in Chrome with the onload event handler for the File API FileReader class the file is only processed properly the second time it's selected in the form.

Any idea how I can get Chrome to process this event the first time around?
In my console network when i click edit image don't appear nothing when i click the second time in edit button appear me the profilePic with the image blob.
IDK what happen.

Code:

```
function uploadFile(){
    var file = $scope.profilePic;
    console.log(file);
    var blob = new Blob([file], {
        "type": "text/html"
    });

    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
        var text = e.target.result.split(',')[1];
        console.log(text);
        $scope.loadedUser.profilePic = text;
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
};
```

html:

```
<div layout-gt-sm="row" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">                                                    
    <input type="file" name="profilePic" fileread="profilePic"> 
</div>
```

Comment: I'm confused, if it is an image, why do you create an html blob of it, and actually, why do you even create a blob of the File??? Files are Blobs.

Comment: I need convert my image to blob to send the backend.

Comment: But "a File is a Blob" ! Whatever you can do with a Blob can be done with a File too. You don't need to convert it, and moreover not to something it is not.

Comment: but how the backend convert the file to blob for DB? I am convert in frontend because the backend send to DB already converted

Comment: No you don't get it. In the code you posted, you are converting a File, from a file input into an text/html Blob. File Object is a superset of Blob and shares all the properties of it, + a name. So a FileReader can read a File directly. No need to convert it to a Blob. But since we're there, it is better to send your file directly as a multipart request to the server (thanks to the FormData API) and do your b64 conversion server side. I don't know what you're using server side but I am sure there is a clean way to handle.multipart files and to convert anything to b64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick fix is to use `$scope.$apply`:

```
reader.onload = function(e) {
    var text = e.target.result.split(',')[1];
    console.log(text);
    $scope.loadedUser.profilePic = text;
    //USE $apply
    $scope.$apply();
}
```

The `reader.onload` event is a browser event which occurs outside the AngularJS framework. Any changes to the AngularJS scope need to be processed with an AngularJS digest cycle which is started with `$scope.$apply()`.

[image]
<sub>(source: [angularjs.org](https://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/img/guide/concepts-runtime.png))</sub>

-- [AngularJS Developer Guide (v1.1.5) - Concepts - Runtime](https://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/guide/concepts#runtime)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But when i try update the image i continue with the same error. It's only been 2 times since. I am stuck in this problem

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with `<object>` tag and blob file.

I got data of the file from server and make a blob file of it and tried to show it in a modal using `<object>` tag.
Every thing did well until I added a loading icon and hence a loading flag (or variable). I utilized `ng-if` to handle `<object>` tag with this loading flag.
This caused `<object>` tag not loading correctly. Since then, file was not showed for the first time I opened the modal, but was showed correctly when I opened the modal for the second time, I didn't get the file from server for the second time and hence no loading (no loading for the second time because file was already in access).

To overcome this problem, I tried and changed many things with no success.
`$scope.$apply()` didn't work for me. Then I changed the flag `ng-if` to `ng-show`, by this way the `<object>` loaded for the first time correctly and hence file was showed too.