# Reader.onload upload image file to blob angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm in this problem a days. What happens is the following when I try to click the update image button I can not do the image update on the first try despite my console.log it return me the correct value. What happens is that when I make the request to the backend the first time I load the update button it always returns the blob of the image that was previously and when I try again it returns the blob of the image that I tried to perform in the previous moment and Inserts into DB. In short he is always with a late request and I do not do the least because. I already tried to add the $ scope. $ Apply () and it did not work.

[image]

[First update the blob of the previous image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmmNo.png)

[image]

[Second update the blob correct of the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkgV0.png)

In short I need to do update twice to be able to change the image to the one I want.

**Code:**

```
function uploadFile(){
    var file = $scope.profilePic;
    var blob = new Blob([file], {
        "type": "text/html"
    });

    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
        $scope.text = e.target.result.split(',')[1];
        $scope.loadedUser.profilePic = $scope.text;
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);

};
```

**Html:**

```
<div layout-gt-sm="row" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">                                                    
    <input type="file" name="profilePic" fileread="profilePic"> 
</div>
```

**APP:**

```
app.directive("fileread", [function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            fileread: "="
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
            element.bind("change", function (changeEvent) {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    scope.fileread = changeEvent.target.files[0];
                    // or all selected files:
                    // scope.fileread = changeEvent.target.files;
                });
            }); 
        } 
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem is that the directive uses two-way `=` binding with isolate scope. A digest cycle is necessary to transfer the data from the isolate scope to the parent scope.

One approach is to use expression `&` binding and expose the file as a local:

```
<div layout-gt-sm="row" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
    <input type="file" name="profilePic" fileread="profilePic = $file">
</div>
```

```
app.directive("fileread", function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            //fileread: "="
            fileread: "&"
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
            element.bind("change", function (changeEvent) {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                var file = changeEvent.target.files[0];
                scope.fileread({$file: file});
                scope.$apply()
            }); 
        } 
    }
});
```

In the above example, when a change event occurs, the directive evaluates the Angular expression defined by the `fileread` attribute with the file exposed as `$file`. The `$file` value is immediately available to the parent scope without the need of a watcher (and digest cycle) to transfer the value from isolate scope to parent scope.

Another problem is that `reader.onload` event occurs outside the AngularJS framework and needs a `$scope.$apply()` to process the changes to scope. For more information, see [SO: FileReader onload only works the second time around in browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41430901/filereader-onload-only-works-the-second-time-around-in-browsers).